# How to move labels from top to left and make the inputs 100% long in a flex form?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In other words, how to get from this:

[image]

To something like this:

[image]

In other words, from labels on top of the input to labels on the left side of the input while making the input fit the parent's width.

```css
.row {
      display: flex
    }
    
    .form-group {
      display: flex
      flex: 1 0 0
      flex-direction: column
    }
    
    .col-12 {
      //
    }
    
    .col-6 {
      //
    }
    
    .col-4 {
      //
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-6">First name</label>
    <input class="col-6" type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-6">Last name</label>
    <input class="col-6" type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-8" type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-12" type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-12" type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-12" type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `display:flex` on your `row`- declaring it on the `form-group` is sufficient. Then you add the according flex properties on the child elements (`input` and `label`).

Also very important: Always insert `;` after each declaration, or you will break the entire rule block.

```css
/* essential rules */
.form-group {
  display: flex;
}
label {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
input {
  flex: 1;
}


/* only for style */
.form-group {
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
input{
  padding:.4em;
  border-radius:2px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
label {
  padding:.4em;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-6">First name</label>
    <input class="col-6" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-6">Last name</label>
    <input class="col-6" type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-8" type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-12" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-12" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-4">Message</label>
    <input class="col-12" type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: `input`s are void elements. They don't take closing tags.